# Quelle est la différence entre « aussi » et « également » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Question simple… D'habitude j'utilise ces deux mots comme synonymes, mais je reconnais (au moins il me semble) qu'il y a une petite différence entre les deux. C'est quoi ?

Answer (score 7):

[Aussi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aussi) et [également](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9galement) ont des sens propres, ils ne sont pas systématiquement substituable (*Une longue table sur laquelle une nappe étroite dont les pans retombent également aux deux bouts.*, *aussi gaiement que possible*).  Dans les cas où ils le sont, personnellement, je ne perçois pas de nuance de sens.

Comment: You can say that? "Ils le sont"?

Comment: @Aerovistae, yes.

Comment: The mystery deepens...

Comment: @Aerovistae It is possible to use pronouns (here _le_ is a pronoun) to refer to adjectives.

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que aussi ajoute à également une connotation d'addition.

Si je dis *Mon frère est allé à la piscine, et au parc aussi*, je peux comprendre *et au parc en plus* ; mais si je dis *Mon frère est allé à la piscine, et au parc également*, je ne le peux plus.

(et vous ? )

Le TLFI traite précisément du cas où aussi veut dire également, au [II du mot aussi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aussi). Heureusement pour moi, il exprime également (hein) l'arrière plan d'idée d'addition pour aussi.

> II. Le mot signifie également, pareillement.
>
> A. Avec un verbe exprimé ou sous-entendu, il exprime la réitération
>   d'un procès :
>
> 1. ... l'arc-en-ciel n'a pas ce degré de réalité ou de consistance objective; il n'existe en tel lieu de l'espace que relativement à tel
>      observateur placé dans un lieu déterminé; de sorte que, l'observateur
>      se déplaçant, l'arc se déplace aussi, ou même s'évanouit tout à fait :
>      ... COURNOT, Essai sur les fondements de nos connaissances, 1851, p.
> 2. Le verbe étant sous-entendu, aussi porte sur un pron. pers. à forme accentuée. Moi, toi, lui aussi :
> 3. L'aveugle reprit : Nous n'avons toujours pas de nouvelles de Venture? Aucune, et cela m'inquiète. Moi aussi, écrivit l'aveugle.
>      PONSON DU TERRAIL, Rocambole, t. 5, Les Exploits de Rocambole, 1859,
>      p. 232.
>
> B. Avec un verbe, subst. ou adj., il exprime une idée d'addition.
>   1. Avec verbe. Il y a aussi :
>
> 1. Il y avait aussi des illustrations de bals publics, des comédiennes du boulevard; et ce n'était pas les plus belles qui
>      recevaient le plus d'hommages. FLAUBERT, L'Éducation sentimentale, t.
>      2, 1869, p. 6.
> 2. Avec un subst. :
> 3. Michaud aussi fut amoureux d'elle. SAINTE-BEUVE, Pensées et maximes, 1869, p. 104.
> 4. Avec un adj. :
> 5. Chaude, humide et douce aussi est l'heure qui précède le soir. MICHELET, L'Insecte, 1857, p. 322. Avec un adv. ou une loc. de temps.
>      Quelquefois aussi, parfois aussi, la plupart du temps aussi, pour la
>      première fois aussi :
> 6. Est-ce que ce coffret demeure là habituellement? demanda-t-il. Quelquefois. Quelquefois aussi, le duc le remet dans le secrétaire.
>      Mais il est ce matin sur la table et le duc est trop agité pour s'en
>      occuper. PONSON DU TERRAIL, Rocambole, t. 5, Les Exploits de
>      Rocambole, 1859, p. 132.
> 7. Elle se taisait modestement. Parfois aussi elle prêtait à ces choses un tout autre sens et mêlait un petit mot à la conversation,
>      ... MICHELET, Journal, 1849-60, p. 578.
> 8. Par deux fois aussi, il lui jeta au feu ses livres de prières, ses chapelets, ses médailles et les images bénites, ... REIDER, Mlle
>      Vallantin, 1862, p. 30.

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que l'on choisira plus couramment *aussi* pour remplacer un **sujet** répété (avec objet sous-entendu), et plus souvent *également* pour un **objet** répété (donc cette fois avec sujet sous-entendu).

Exemples :

> Mon frère est allé à la piscine, et au parc également.
>
> Mon frère est allé à la piscine, et sa copine aussi.

Ces choix me semblent plus naturels que les versions (*... au parc aussi* / *... sa copine également*), qui ne sont pas incorrects mais probablement un peu moins fréquents.

Comment: _sa copine également_ ne me gène pas du tout. Je dirais _et aussi au parc_ plutôt que _et au parc aussi_.

Comment: Ca ne me gêne pas le moins du monde non plus. J'avais le sentiment que c'était moins fréquent.

Answer (score 0):

"Aussi" et "également" peuvent être en général interchangeables sauf quand on utilise "aussi" dans le comparatif d'égalité. Ex: Il est aussi grand que son frère. Dans tous les autres cas, il s'agit de préférence personnelle.